# Multiple web apps on same compute engine

Tags: .net, google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-compute-engine

I have a .NET MVC application (front end) that communicates with a Web API application (back end) and I am migrating from Azure to GCP.

Using Google Cloud Platform, is it possible to have both MVC and Web API web applications (.NET Framework) on the same compute engine instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.  The Compute Engine Instance is running Internet Information Server (IIS), and IIS can run multiple websites.

I'll describe how to do it using [Google Cloud Tools for Visual Studio](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GoogleCloudTools.GoogleCloudPlatformExtensionforVisualStudio).

1. Download a `.publishsettings` file for your webserver.  In Visual Studio's Google Cloud Explorer window, right click the compute engine instance and choose **Save publishing settings...**
   [image]
2. Save the `.publishsettings` file locally.
3. In Visual Studio's Solution Explorer Window, right-click your application name, and choose **Publish...**
   [image]
4. Select **Import profile**, click the gear icon in the bottom right, and click **Create Profile**.
   [image]
5. In the project window, click **Settings...**
   [image]
6. In the Publish window, give each app a unique **Site name** and **Destination url**.
   [image]
7. Click **Save**.
8. Click **Publish**.
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

Google Compuete Engine refers to Google managed virtual machine, you should be able to host both front and backend services with no issues.